# Problemas con scrollTop para anclas en HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy haciendo una pagina la cual al hacerle clic a una opción del menú este va a un ancla de esta misma. Hasta hay bien.  Cuando utilizo el siguiente código en jquery para el desplazamiento

```
$('nav a').click(function(e){               
        e.preventDefault();     //evitar el eventos del enlace normal
        enlace  = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({       
         scrollTop: $(enlace).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

En la consola aparece el siguiente mensaje

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

En los ejemplos que encuentro por internet veo que la utilizan pero a mi no me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el metodo offset() y llamar la propiedad top:

```
$('nav a').click(function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); //evitar el eventos del enlace normal enlace = 
$(this).attr('href'); 
$('html, body').animate({ 
scrollTop: $(enlace).offset().top 
}, 
1000); 
});
```

El metodo offset() devuelve un objeto que contiene 2 propiedades **top** y **left** y estas contienen un valor entero especificando la posición de un elemento.

Eso lo tienes bien el problema es el elemento que no se esta obteniendo con el selector que usas es posible que *nav* sea una clase por lo que en vez de nav debes poner *.nav*.

Comment: Muchas gracias.  el error era en el elemento que se obtiene en el selector.  Como esta función la estoy implementando en WORDPRESS se debe de colocar tambien la etiqueta "ul" y "li".  $('nav ul li a').click(function(e){